# Drawing a line between 2 points on the map in leaflet using the shortest distance first

Tags: r, leaflet

Good afternoon,

First off let me start sharing my code (I hope its in a adequate format so its legible).

```
Locaties <- data.frame(
  Naam = c("Adress van X","Adress van A", "Adress van A V"),
  lon = c(3.968863, 3.861206, 4.916565),        
  lat = c(51.320180, 52.208229, 51.345988)   
)

leaflet(data = Locaties) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$Wikimedia)%>% 
  addCircleMarkers(
    lng = ~lon, 
    lat = ~lat, 
    radius = 6,
    color = "red", 
    label = paste("locatie" = Locaties$Naam)) %>% 
  addPolylines(
    lng = ~lon,
    lat = ~lat,
    group = ~Naam.
    opacity = 0.2,
    color="green",
    weight= 4)
```

*For privacy the locations were changed so it doesn't make sense, visually.
The output of this code is :

[image]

The red line is the code, and the black line is what I would want to happen. I would like a "start point" to be connected to "all" the other points using the shortest distance possible. What it is doing now is ether an arbitrary selection or something else. I would like to know if this is posible to achieve using just leaflet, and if not please give me a direction/hint as to where to look as I do understand this forum is not meant to just give out the answer if you haven't tried anything yourself.

Thanks again! And please do comment if I did something wrong/if it could be formulated better, my first language isn't English.

Comment: You mean to solve the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)? Have you looked at the [`TSP` package for R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSP/versions/1.1-10)?

Comment: I just read up on the links you told me about, and it seems to be the exact thing im looking for thank you! now i just have to figure out how to put it into code and wrap my head around it a tat more.